# How to extract javascript variable value using imacros browser?

Tags: javascript, imacros

I have looked but I simply cannot find an answer to what I expect should be a very simple task.

I have navigated to a page that contains a known javascript variable.

eg: var foo='my variable text';

How can I extract that value ('my variable text') using iMacros browser? Is that even possible to do directly?

Or, would I have to execute javascript to place that variable's value into an input or tag, that iMacros can then extract from?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `URL GOTO` method to call a javascript function, which will load the value inside the input element. Please checkout the below example where I have replicated the same.

**HTML:**

```
<script>
var a  = "naren";
</script>
<input type="text" id="naren"/>
```

**IMacros:**

```
VERSION BUILD=9030808 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=javascript:{(function<SP>(){console.log(document.getElementById(a).value='works!')})()}
```

So I have made a mockup page with the html as above, then ran the below imacros.

Some  points you need to know about calling the imacros script are:

I have wrapped the anonymous function as an [`iife`](http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/an-introduction-to-iffes-immediately-invoked-function-expressions.html), long story short, the function will get executed immediately.

If you visit the [`IMACROS URL wiki page`](https://wiki.imacros.net/URL) There is a line which tells us.

> The URL GOTO command by default outputs the result of the evaluated
>   Javascript expression on a new page in the current tab. If you want to
>   manipulate an element on the page and don't want the result to be
>   processed by the URL GOTO command, you need to wrap it in some other
>   call or expression that does not evaluate to any value.
>
> For example, to change the value of the Name field on the demo Fill
>   Form page, you can wrap the call in console.log() as follows:
>
> **URL GOTO=http://demo.imacros.net/Automate/TestForm1 URL
>   GOTO=javascript:console.log(document.getElementById("name").value='Test');**

So I have implement the above statement by wrapping the assignment done to the input element inside a `console.log`.

Please let me know if you have issues implementing this solution!

Comment: Thanks so much for the response. I believe the section you posted from the wiki page was the key info I was missing/overlooking.