# iMacros Tag Line properties

Tags: vba, excel, imacros

I'm trying to create a macro to log in to a company owned web page.  When I record putting the cursor into the User Name text box, the following command is recorded:

TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:/pdp/qnyfy/resumeSAML50/pdp/startSSO.ping

The problem is that the "qnyfy" part of the tag line changes.  The next time I try to record this tag line, every thing is the same except that "qnyfy" changes to something else; which renders my VBA code useless for logging into this web page.

Is there a way to extract this information first, find out what that 5 characters should be and then re-build a string to use the correct tag line?

Windows 7
Excel 2016
iMacros 10.3

Thanks for the help........

Comment: is there something preventing you from reading it into a string variable and using that variable to set the tag?   if you posted your code then it may help get a better answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, @OP opened some parallel Thread on the iMacros Forum ([iMacros Tag Line Properties](https://forum.imacros.net/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=29692)), which allows me to simplify a bit this Answer and to remove a few of the original IF-IF-IF...
(The parallel Thread contains a bit more (Background) Info and more precise Sols/Scripts applied to this specific Script, for those interested...)

First, FCI (Full Config Info) was originally not completely clear, now it is:
=> iMB v10.3, 'Scripting Interface' v10.3, Win7.
("iMacros v10.3" could have meant 'v10.3 for CR 'Free'/'PE'' also...)

(The 'TAG' Statement is truncated is this Thread, it is complete + complete Script in the parallel Thread...)

Several Solutions, I'll go from "simplest" to "more complex":

1- The 'FORM' Parameter can probably simply completely be removed. It is usually not needed, unless there are several Forms on the Page with similar HTML Elements, here the 'INPUT' Field.

2- Same like '1', but using for example the 'CLASS' Attribute or any Attr(s) that might identify this 'INPUT' Field uniquely if there are several Forms on the Page with similar (but not identical) 'INPUT' Fields. (Or by adjusting the 'POS=n' if they are identical...)

3- Same like '1' or '2', but combined with 'Relative Positioning', on some HTML Element that can be identified "easily" and uniquely to be used as the Anchor, either inside ('3a') the same 'FORM' or 'DIV' (=> this 'INPUT' probably has some 'Label' next to it like some "Login:" for example), or just outside ('3b') if that Form has some Name/Title for that "Section", usually in 'H2' or 'H3' Type.

4- Simply replace the dynamic part ("qnyfy") with a Wildcard:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:/pdp/*/resumeSAML50/pdp/startSSO.ping
```

Sols [1-4] probably provide a "Shortcut" to probably achieve the desired Result, but they actually don't really answer @OP's Qt which was "How to identify/extract/isolate this "qnyfy" 5 Letter String...?"

5- Using first one of [1-4] Methods, manage to tag some Element that will be inside that 'FORM', either the 'INPUT' Field itself or one Element that could be used  as Anchor in '3a' (with Anchor Inside the Form), and then use 'Double Relative Positioning' (more Info on the iMacros Forum where I've several times already completely explained the Principle) to identify and tag and extract (=HTM) the complete 'Containing 'DIV'' (or could be 'SPAN', but there will very probably be some (outer) 'DIV' also) containing the 'FORM' to then isolate the "qnyfy" part using 'EVAL', stg like...:

```
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:/pdp/*/resumeSAML50/pdp/startSSO.ping ATTR=CLASS:* EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=R-1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
SET !EXTRACT NULL
TAG POS=R1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:*&&CLASS:* EXTRACT=HTM
SET Form_ID EVAL("var s='{{!EXTRACT}}'; var x,y,z; x=s.split('ACTION:/pdp/'); y=x[1].split('/'); z=y[0]; z;")
PROMPT EXTRACT:<BR><BR>{{!EXTRACT}}<BR><BR>Form_ID:<SP>_{{Form_ID}}_
```

6- This one actually comes between '4' and '5', it would be by using '3b' to first locate some Anchor *outside* the 'FORM' and its 'Containing 'DIV'', then only one Level of 'Relative Positioning' would be needed... (And the 'EVAL()' Statement remains the same...)

That's it...! It would help / add some "Reliability" if for example the Class of the Containing 'DIV' can be identified/added.

Not relevant for iMB v10.3 anymore:
And if "iMacros v10.3" meant "iMacros for CR v10.3 'Free'", you'll need to use ['!VAR1'-'!VAR3'] instead of 'Form_ID' as User Defined Vars are not supported in the 'Free' Version...

[All Solutions/Scripts not tested of course...! Hum, I had previously mentioned that I could directly think of 3 or 4 Solutions, here are already 6, ah-ah...!, and there are also different possible Variants on all 6 of them...]

7- In the parallel Thread on the iMacros Forum, I also mentioned and explained about a Sol_7 using the 'EVENT' Mode with or without ID, which wouldn't be of use for this User as the 'EVENT' Mode was not supported in iMB v10.3.

Rmk:
Sol_5 and Sol_6 can actually be used to deal with Dynamic ID's, same Principle...!

> >

I might one day have to delete this Answer as I am currently (re)using each time my last 5/5 'Answer_Credit', I each time have to delete some previous Answer, to be able to post a 5th one, as most Users on the 'iMacros' Tag-Channel usually never follow up on their Threads and don't do "+1" or "Accept Solution"..., and all my previous Answers also usually all get downvoted anyway by some "angry" User(s), so I never manage to pass the Threshold for more than 5 Answers, ah-ah...!, tja...!
(No big deal probably as I actually never or very-very rarely answer Threads on SOF as I don't like the Rep-Pts System, I only answered this one because @OP is a "nice User" that I knew from the iMacros Forum, ah-ah...!)

(I still don't know what the 'community wiki' CB means below posting an Answer...?)

Comment: Hum, and you'll get a '+1' from me on your Qt @Shaves once you'll have posted your FCI a bit more "complete" and more clear, and your complete 'TAG' Statement as well, that you've half truncated...

Comment: Yep I will, waiting for OP to check their Thread again and to open a parallel Thread on the iMacros Forum... There are several Solutions with a lot of IF-IF-IF, I will then post the final "clean" Solution here...
Oh, but sorry, you mean the Thread you link to @Naren Murali, hum, yep, I had seen it, but they combine that Functionality with Temp/Fake E-mail Addresses, typical Spam Behaviour, but I don't help for Spam (nor for Social Media)... [Hum, the 'Add Comment' Button doesn't work...(?)]

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have asked the user to raise a question there instead, I hope his intentions are not for spamming, thanks for your time :)

Comment: Yeah well, I doubt it, ah-ah...! Oh...!, but good though..., if they (the User about the 'gmx' Addresses and fake Names) open a Thread on the iMacros Forum, I'll be able to check the "Spam Reputation" of their IP-Address,  ah-ah...! Then I'll see... Yeah, but nope, even if they are not a Spammer, the same Script/Functionality could/would be used by (other) Spammers... (And they could find the Sol by themselves if they searched the iMacros Forum a bit, I've already answered that kind of Qt's many times, ah-ah...!)

Comment: Hum, and @Naren Murali, I had seen you were answering regularly a few iMacros Threads since a few weeks, very nice...! (I think I had upvoted a few of your Answers...) You are always welcome on the iMacros Forum as well, ah-ah...! (Like I mentioned, I don't help for Spam + Social Media + Games/Votes + Captcha, but you are free to still answer those Threads if you want...)

Comment: @Naren Murali, I've  posted my "Answer" anyway as 'OP' was not reacting, with several Solutions... You may want to have a look if you are interested, the "Principle" is not very complicated...

Comment: Thanks for checking out my answers :) I'm a big fan of IMacros software for years, will try to get into IMacros Forums :) I read your detailed post, I think OP needs to do some studying and find the solution :) after reading this answer, I was wondering, if we could fill the input elements and submit the form too using this method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51793237/how-to-extract-javascript-variable-value-using-imacros-browser/51796458#51796458), I got this from the IMacros forums I guess

Comment: @Naren Murali, foufff...!, very cumbersome, I would have found some much simpler Solution, ah-ah...! (The "+1" is from me, ah-ah...!) But low Quality Qt, FCI not mentioned, I had seen that Thread indeed, and was waiting if they would open a Thread on the iMacros Forum...
>> Then,  yep of course, you could use that Method here as well, but you'll still need to identify the 'INPUT' Element, it doesn't really solve the "qnyfy" Dynamic Part...
>> And I think this 'URL GOTO=javascript' Syntax might not be supported anymore in v9.0.3 for FF + v10.x for CR+FF...

Comment: Yes, its deprecated, just wanted ur opinion :) seemed like a good hack for extracting data, anyway thanks for all your contributions in the forums :) I'm sure I would have referenced those answers multiple times :)

Comment: @Naren Murali... or it solves it (the Dynamic Part) just in the same way like "my" Sol_1 and Sol_2 by simply ignoring the 'FORM' Parameter... Then I prefer my Sol_[1-2], ah-ah...!, much simpler... >> I think I only know of 2 or 3 very specific (and pretty "High Level") "Cases" where this Method/Syntax can indeed be useful as Workaround on the 'TAG' or 'EVENT' Modes, Advanced Users 'iimfun' and 'thecoder2012' on the iMacros Forum have used it a few times in some "Legit" Cases...

Comment: I wouldn't qualify it as a "good Hack", especially for Extracting, as "communicating" between the 'URL GOTO' and the rest of the ('.iim') Script is a complete Hassle, you need to create on the fly some custom HTML Element or some Attribute on the 'TITLE' for example to then later re-extract it from the '.iim' Script, very cumbersome... >> If it's already in the Source, some straightforward 'EXTRACT=HTM' on some High Level Element on the Page will contain it as well...

Comment: oh ok, it wont be the best method, will checkout the forums and also your comments, still have a long way to go :D

Comment: Oh, and @Naren Murali, some (Off-Topic) "stupid" Qt, do you know what the 'community wiki' CB (CheckBox) means, just below the Edit/Input Field when posting an Answer...? There is no Alt/Title Info on it, I'm too lazy to "investigate"...!

Comment: Appologies, I am not sure about that checkbox, sorry :(